# SQL Count duplicities

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have problem with marking (BIT) duplicate rows among two columns

> Company & Invoice (Invoice No.)

.

Every code I have tried doesn't work well and ignore the second column. Watch this [printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhG8T.jpg).
This example shows, that each of my codes mark company "348 DOHNAL Otakar" as duplicity incorrectly.

I tried these codes:

```
CAST((CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TabPosta Posta WHERE Posta.Invoice = TabPosta.Invoice GROUP BY Posta.Company HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as BIT)
```

or

```
CAST(CASE WHEN TabPosta.Invoice IN(SELECT Invoice FROM TabPosta GROUP BY Invoice HAVING COUNT(1) > 1) AND TabPosta.Company IN(SELECT Company FROM TabPosta GROUP BY Company HAVING COUNT(1) > 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
```

Would you be so kind and help me, please?

Petr

Comment: please tag your DBMS, show some sample data.

Comment: Is it related to Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft SQL Server ... What way would you like sample date in? Sorry, I am amateur. I could send you an spreadsheet, or you can connect with me vie Skype.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
declare @sampleData table
    (
     Company nvarchar(50),
     InvoiceNo int
    );

insert  into @sampleData
        (Company, InvoiceNo)
values  (N'64 DUKA Colours BARVY LAKY', 652015),
        (N'64 DUKA Colours BARVY LAKY', 652015),
        (N'348 DOHNAL Otakar', 652015);

-- Show sample data
select  *
from    @sampleData as sd;

-- Show duplicates for the two columns
select  *
from    @sampleData as sd
group by sd.Company,
        sd.InvoiceNo
having  count(1) > 1;

--Bringing it all together
select  sd.*,
        d.Duplicate
from    @sampleData as sd
left join (
           select   sd.Company,
                    sd.InvoiceNo,
                    cast(1 as bit) as Duplicate
           from     @sampleData as sd
           group by sd.Company,
                    sd.InvoiceNo
           having   count(1) > 1
          ) as d
        on sd.Company = d.Company
           and sd.InvoiceNo = d.InvoiceNo
```

Comment: Oh, thank you a lot. I would try to implement. But I may have described it wrong way. I do it now presicely. We are scaning incoming invoices and before we do it, we note it in table mentioned above. There are thousands of rows (invoices) per year. But, we are always scaning the same invoice twice, just because we are not able to detect duplicate rows. So, we need a procedure to detect duplicates in BIT column , that will stop us before scan already scanned invoice.

Comment: This is exactly what my script does: detect / show duplicates. There is even a separate bit column as you asked for.  Maybe you don't understand the answer?

Comment: It must be understood that any computer can only show duplicates once an invoice has already been duplicated in the computer. Even if you connect the scan program to your database, the computer needs to scan the document first before it can say if that invoice had been already in the database (= scanned a duplicate).

Answer (score 0):

I will show you [sample date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbbxM.jpg).

I have just tried insert computed column again with this

```
CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM TabPosta as posta
      GROUP BY posta.CisOrg, posta.Znacka 
      HAVING count(1) > 1)
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
```

I don't work. It's result is for all rows always 1. The second code from my question work at least above one column **Znacka**

Comment: Or I have tried unsuccesfully this

CAST(
CASE WHEN COUNT(posta.Znacka) 
FROM TabPosta posta
GROUP BY CisOrg
HAVING ( COUNT(posta.CisOrg) > 1 )
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)